# Using f-string and raw string at same time

Tags: python, regex, pandas, f-string, rawstring

I have a dataframe like this:

```
           p          q
0      jdkdn  01JAN2020
1  01JAN2020   hdk789dj
2      783i3  01FEB2020
```

I am trying to replace `01JAN2020` by `01-01-2020`, basically `alphabetical month name` to `numeric month number`. I don't know where these `date` are, mean in any column and any row. I have tried to do it by just using `df.replace` but having problem with raw string and I want to use f-string as well.
Here's my try:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df=pd.DataFrame({"p":["jdkdn","01JAN2020","783i3"],"q":["01JAN2020","hdk789dj","01FEB2020"]})

months = {'JAN': '01', 'FEB': '02'}
#All 12 months but for test I am using just 2

df.replace(r'(\d{2})('+'|'.join(months)+')(\d{4})',r"\1-"+

f"{{months[\\2]}}" # Here I am trying to do main things

+r"-\3",regex=True,inplace=True)
print(df)
"""
                       p                      q
0                  jdkdn  01-{months[JAN]}-2020
1  01-{months[JAN]}-2020               hdk789dj
2                  783i3  01-{months[FEB]}-2020
"""

fr"{{months[\\2]}}"
"""
                      p                     q
0                 jdkdn  01-{months[\2]}-2020
1  01-{months[\2]}-2020              hdk789dj
2                 783i3  01-{months[\2]}-2020
"""

rf"{months[\2]}" and rf"{months[\\2]}"
"""
SyntaxError: f-string expression part cannot include a backslash
"""
```

**Idea:**
Can we use `regex if` like `(?(<month name>)<number>)`?, Any function in pandas that will detect any `01JAN2020` replace that with `01-01-2020`.

**Expected output is:**

```
           p           q
0      jdkdn  01-01-2020
1 01-01-2020    hdk789dj
2      783i3  01-02-2020
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pandas str. replace, simply create a pattern with names, and the replacements, and use `transform` to apply it to all the columns:

```
pat = r"(?P<day>\d+)(?P<month>[A-Z]+)(?P<year>\d+)"
repl = lambda m: f"{m.group('day')}-{months[m.group('month')]}-{m.group('year')}"

df.transform(lambda x: x.str.replace(pat, repl, regex=True))
 
            p           q
0       jdkdn  01-01-2020
1  01-01-2020    hdk789dj
2       783i3  01-02-2020
```

Note that for strings, if you want more performance, you could write it within python and apply. You can use `re.sub` for that, it should give noticeable improvements (pls test):

```
df.applymap(lambda x: re.sub(pat, repl, x))
```

If your data is duplicated, an efficient approach would be to convert to a Categorical and apply the string modification to the categories; that should be faster.

Kindly note that nulls are covered implicitly by pandas string functions, within python, your code should cover these possible scenarios.

Comment: Yeah! Performance is necessary because I have to do this job for the 20M file.

Comment: Sorry my bad I have forget to do `df=df.transform(lambda x: ` I have just copy/paste and now realize you are printing `df.transform(lambda x: ` yeah! It is working perfectly fine. And performance? What you mean by _within python and apply_?

Comment: Main difference between `apply` and `applymap`? Because I have tested just now, and using just `apply` is also working for me perfectly.

Comment: applymap hits each cell, apply deals with either the entire column or row ... again you should test each for performance ... if you really care about that ... but do not worry on microseconds differences

Comment: Performance test : `.applymap()`,`apply()` and `transform`.

Comment: what if data has `NaN`? Transform and map is working fine but applymap is giving error. TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: ahhh ... I should have mentioned that. .. transform, and pandas string options cover those edge cases, applymap doesnt, since plain python functions are used.

Comment: Actually `.apply()` is faster then `tranform()`